# NG serve can't find ssl files

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-core, angular12

I try to run default ASP.NET 6 angular project template and unfortunately npm start fails by exception

```
"start:windows": "ng serve --port 8001 --ssl --ssl-cert %APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\${npm_package_name}.pem --ssl-key %APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\${npm_package_name.key}",

An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\ffres\Documents\GitHub\NFTMarketPlace\MarketPlace\MarketPlace\ClientApp\%APPDATA%\ASP.NET\https\${npm_package_name}.key'
```

But weirdly if i remove --ssl-cert parameter, it works fine. Surely i need -ssl-cert parameter as well.

```
"start:windows": "ng serve --port 8001 --ssl --ssl-key %APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\${npm_package_name}.key"
```

I can't use absolute full path in here so i need to use AppData and npm_package_name variables in path.

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue if your windows account has a space in the name. It's been merged into the main repo but I don't believe the template has been updated.

[Github](https://github.com/dotnet/spa-templates/pull/35)

Change your start to this

```
"ng serve --ssl --ssl-cert \"%APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.pem\" --ssl-key \"%APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.key\""
```

We wrap the path in quotes in case there's a space. Notice the double quotes on the end as well.